# drop down menu displayed behind embedded reportviewer object

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer, reporting-services

I'm adding an embedded reportviewer object to an existing web forms solution.  In Edge and Chrome it works as desired, but in IE11, the dropdown menu goes behind the report object.

How do I fix this?

**IE11**

[image]

**Edge**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.

Apparently my company uses compatibility mode for intranet sites.  When I turned that off, the drop down problem went away.

[This page was helpful](https://forums.asp.net/p/1880393/5292631.aspx?Re%20Dropdown%20menu%20appearing%20behind%20report%20viewer%20server%20only%20) in pointing me in the right direction.